# Why is my if statement not being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I'm using if statements in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so I can populate cells with the right images.

```
if ([object objectForKey:@"type"] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]) {

    self.cell.typeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type1"];
}

else if ([object objectForKey:@"type"] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {

    self.cell.artTypeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type2"];
}

else if ([object objectForKey:@"type"] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]) {

    self.cell.artTypeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type3"];
}
```

To clarify, I do get a value for `[object objectForKey:@"type"]`, as it does not return nil.

Comment: An if statement is not getting "called" because it is not a function. As to why its *body* might not be *executed:* as Objective-C objects are pointers, `==` compares identity (pointer equality) rather than semantic equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare two NSNumbers with `isEqualToNumber:`, not `==`.

Additionally modifying the NSNumbers to have `[NSNumber intValue]` will allow `==` to work.

You need to modify each of your if statements and it should work.